# In batch programming, how to use a user key-in input as to print out array content

Tags: arrays, variables, batch-file, echo

```
@echo off
set myArray[0]=a1
set myArray[1]=b2
set myArray[2]=c3
set myArray[3]=d4
set myArray[4]=e5
set myArray[5]=f6
set myArray[6]=g7
set myArray[7]=h8
set myArray[8]=i8
set myArray[9]=j9

set /p TEMPCMD:

echo %myArray[%TEMPCMD%]%
echo %myArray[!TEMPCMD!]%
echo !myArray[%TEMPCMD%]!
echo !myArray[!TEMPCMD!]!
```

I want to print out the array content based on what user key-in index, but none of the case above works in this case... I understand that `!variable!` is only be used when `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`, but I just take a trial for that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, you can do that with the `EnableDelayedExpansion` option. It seems that you missed to turn that flag on. Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set myArray[0]=a1
set myArray[1]=b2
set myArray[2]=c3
set myArray[3]=d4
set myArray[4]=e5
set myArray[5]=f6
set myArray[6]=g7
set myArray[7]=h8
set myArray[8]=i8
set myArray[9]=j9

SET /P TEMPCMD=Input index:
echo !myArray[%TEMPCMD%]!
```

Comment: Thanks...i made the mistake somewhere in my full code cause me to debug for 1hour ++

Answer (score 2):

Here is another method:

```
@echo off
set myArray[0]=a1
set myArray[1]=b2
set myArray[2]=c3
set myArray[3]=d4
set myArray[4]=e5
set myArray[5]=f6
set myArray[6]=g7
set myArray[7]=h8
set myArray[8]=i8
set myArray[9]=j9

set /p TEMPCMD=

call echo %%myArray[%TEMPCMD%]%%
pause
```